# KnockoutJS: Spurious callback with large count of observables

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-2.0

I have a page using KnockoutJS, with a somewhat large count of observables (about 35 are relevant here, some 60 total). I use the KO mapping plugin, but I don't know if that has anything to do with my problem.

Most (not all) of the observables are bound to input fields.

The user can save the current set of inputs to a named set, or reload from a previously saved set. There is UI that indicates whether the current set of inputs came from a saved set, or are edited (unsaved) inputs.

In order to update the "save/load inputs" UI when any of the inputs are edited (I don't care which one), I subscribe to all the relevant 'input' observables.

Here's my bizarre problem: when the count of subscribed observables is about 25 or higher, I get a spurious call to my callback function from deep inside the `ko.applyBindings(...)` call.

- When it happens, there is only one spurious callback
- The input that gets reported is typically the last one I subscribed to.
- If I remove enough subscriptions so that I subscribe to about 25 or less, the spurious callback disappears.
- If I pass that limit and I keep adding subscriptions, the call reappears for different fields as I keep adding to the list.
- If I subscribe to all the inputs, then the callback claims to be a callback for `__ko_mapping__` which is absurd.

I have to assume that either I'm not binding to the subscription correctly, or that there is some bug within KO or the KO mapping plugin that causes the list of subscriptions to get messed up. I haven't been able to track the problem so far.

The subscription code looks roughly like this:

```
// markSavedInputsDirty(name) defined elsewhere
function registerCallbacks() {
    var data = viewModel.inputs;
    var member;
    for(member in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(member) && ko.isObservable(data[member])) {
            if(member /* ... not certain observables which I need to ignore */ ) {
                data[member].subscribe(function() {return markSavedInputsDirty(member)}, data[member]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(Note: the code above tracks which member is being called, but only as a debugging aid. When we saw the problem crop up originally, the code used to just use the same callback function (no currying) for all the observables)

Has anybody seen anything like this before?

Comment: In your callback function, `member` won't be accurate. I know you said you had the problem before, but if you want to actually debug it, you should make sure it's correct. To do so you need to save it in a new closure for each subscription. Something like `function(member){data[member].subscribe(...)}(member)`

Comment: @MichaelBest, you're correct. The closure was messed up and that was leading me astray. I will update the post briefly with the resolution. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad you got it figured out. It'd be good for you to add an answer and mark it as accepted so this doesn't stay around as "unanswered". Also I'd appreciate a +1 on my comment. :-)

Comment: I guess I can't Accept my own answer for two days. I'll come back then and mark it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RESOLUTION:**

The closure on the `subscribe(...)` call was messed up, as @MichaelBest indicated in the comments. I though it would contain the value of `member` at the point of invocation, but it contains `member` itself (the object, the same for all calls). What I was seeing was the final value of `member` from the loop, and that was leading me astray. I should not have been doing this at midnight.

Here's a correct implementation of that line:

```
data[member].subscribe(markSavedInputsDirty.bind(data[member], member));
```

Once I had the right diagnostics, everything became clear: the spurious call comes from a `value` binding on a `<select>` element in the page. Knockout internally needs to make sure that the selected `<option>`'s value is exactly the same as the `viewModel`'s value (see `ensureDropdownSelectionIsConsistentWithModelValue(...)` in the source for Knockout).

In my case, the observable value had 3 (number), while the selected `<option>` -- naturally -- had "3" (string). Therefore, Knockout set the viewModel to the option's value, and that triggered the notification.

So, the original subscriptions (before my broken attempt at currying) were correct and the notification was legitimate. I just need to swap things around so my monitoring code doesn't have any effect until after the binding.